# 1970s era Huffy 3 speed Sea Trails chain

Tags: chain

How do I know what size chain fits this bike? Which chain should I purchase?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: you are probably going to a shop to buy the chain? they should be able to tell you

Comment: how do you know this person is not a shopkeeper who is picking the right chain to sell?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @mike. We recommend new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site (and understand what's going on :-) We think your bike has it's gears in the rear hub, and so it has the same chain as a fixed gear bike; see the suggested duplicate.

Comment: Walk into any bike shop and tell them you need a chain for an old 3-speed bike.  (Be sure to get a chain tool as well, to cut the chain to length.)

Answer (score 2):

Any 1/8 inch width bicycle chain will fit.